# Bias of ridge estimator

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

The ridge estimator $(\hat{\beta}_R)$, and the expected value, are defined as;

\begin{align}
   \hat{\beta}_R &= \left( X'X + kI \right)^{-1}X'y, \ k \geq 0 \\
   \text{E}\left( \hat{\beta}_R \right) &= \left( X'X + kI \right)^{-1}X'X \beta
\end{align}

where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$, $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times 1}$, $\beta_R \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times 1}$.

It is stated directly in the textbook "Introduction to Linear Regression Analysis" that the following is true;

\begin{equation}
  \text{Bias} \left( \hat{\beta}_R \right)^2 = \left( E( \hat{\beta}_R ) - \beta  \right)^2 = k^2 \beta' \left( X'X + kI \right)^{-2}\beta
\end{equation}

How can I show this? If I expand the middle term, I get the following

\begin{equation}
  \left( E( \hat{\beta}_R ) - \beta  \right)^2 = E( \hat{\beta}_R )^2 - E( \hat{\beta}_R )\beta - \beta E( \hat{\beta}_R ) + \beta^2
\end{equation}

However, $E( \hat{\beta}_R )  \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times 1}$ and $ \beta \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times 1}$. It appears to me that there is a problem with the dimension. How do I resolve this or is the claim in the textbook false?

Comment: The square of the (Euclidean) norm of a vector $x$ is $x^\intercal x.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As defined, the "squared bias" has no meaning since the bias is a vector. One should consider instead then squared norm of the bias, namely $B^2=[E(\hat{\beta}_R) - \beta]'[E(\hat{\beta}_R) - \beta]$. We have
$$E(\hat{\beta}_R) - \beta= (X'X + k I)^{-1}(X'X - (X'X+kI))\beta=-k (X'X + k I)^{-1}\beta.$$
Therefore,
$$B^2 = k^2 \beta'(X'X + k I)^{-2}\beta.$$